# Tiled - isometric map - how to find out tile width/height

Tags: isometric, tiled, tilesets

so I'm playing aroung with Tiled and want to create an isometric map. I found this tileset:

https://opengameart.org/content/isometric-landscape

The downloaded file contains a big spritesheet with many sprites in it. What is the best way to find out what settings I need to have in Tiled to work with these?

I need to set a tile width/height for the map, and width/height for a tileset itself. What's the best way to find out? The problem with this specific tileset is that the tiles all have different sizes (but it's all in one big image).

There are images of each tile sprite itself, but I don't know how to "mass add" these to Tiled.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The downloaded file contains a big spritesheet with many sprites in it. What is the best way to find out what settings I need to have in Tiled to work with these?

The spritesheet included in that download is not directly usable in Tiled currently, because the images are not aligned to a grid. Rather there is an XML file describing the locations of each tile, which Tiled currently does not support ([#1008](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues/1008)).

> There are images of each tile sprite itself, but I don't know how to "mass add" these to Tiled.

You can mass-add them by creating a new tileset (selecting "Collection of Images") and then clicking the "+" icon in the tool bar and selecting all the files (or use drag-n-drop to drag them to the tileset from your file manager).